# CSS Grid Layout 2 * 3 with multilevel groups

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I try to create a two columns layout [params - rendering] with an undefined number of rows (sometimes 2, sometimes 3) using CSS Grid Layout.

The render column have an specific background regardless to the rows count but the row height is equal between the columns. I suppose that i need to put another tag to do that.

I let you a screenshot of this layout. It's the better example I can give. The pink boxes are the grid layout. For the "render" columns, I have a specific background (white and shadow) that can be created in CSS. I don't want to use a picture for it.

[image: CSS grid layout picture]

[image: CSS grid layout picture 2]

It’s seems what i want to do is like this example **Implicit named grid lines**: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example22/

Comment: You can use `felxbox` for your requirement.

Comment: Height of rows will be equal to content or no? width of columns what would be? Do you need supporting IE/Edge or no?

Comment: The rows are not equal and auto regarding the content.
The width of the columns will be near 20% (params) / 80% (render).
I don't need to support IE but Edge will be great if possible.

Comment: @BenoitHenry Supporting CSS Grid Layout for Edge is the same for IE (using old specs). Maybe something will change in the future. If you are OK with my answer for other browsers I'll add way to use my layout for IE/Edge.

Comment: Do you need cells to span throuh columns or rows  ?

Comment: I updated my post with a new picture. Hope it will help you.

Comment: actually we are missing your html structure and behavior of at least first column . Is it a static width ? are both columns a percentage width or else ?

Comment: Here's a pen i just create : https://codepen.io/bhenbe/pen/eEBwbP

Comment: The overlay in absolute should work : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BdQXyw

Comment: It also works without grid-template-areas : demo : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xLRvwx (hover aside to its row grow)

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify row height because they will be created by default with auto height. Add absolutely positioned pseudoelement with background to add background to right column and preserve element autoplacement.

```css
.grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  
  /* get 20% and remaining width for columns */
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
  
  /* gap between rows and columns */
  grid-gap: 15px;
  
  /* just styles for demo */
  color: #ada0b9;
  padding: 40px;
  
  position: relative;
}

.grid__item {
  padding: 30px;
}

.grid__item--params {
  background-color: #e8d7eb;
}

.grid__item--render {
  background-color: #f8e7fb;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  
  /* also add padding to positioning values */
  left: calc(20% + 40px);
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  
  /* add negative to prevent content overlapping */
  z-index: -1;
  
  /* add needed background styles here */
  background: lime none;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--params">Params#1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--render">Render#1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--params">Params#2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--render">Render#2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--params">Params#3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--render">Render#3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem i meet is to have only one render for the entire render column regardless of the rows. It's why i thought i can add another div element positioned before the .grid__item--render elements to emulate this "group".

Comment: @BenoitHenry Sorry, I didn't understand your requirement. Can you please provide some fiddle (for example jsFiddle) of your issue.

Comment: I edited my post with a second example. Hope it will help you.

Your HTML structure is OK. I just think i need to add a new div.grid__item--renderbackground to add a blank and shadowed background on the entire "render" column.

Comment: @BenoitHenry I wound and background for whole grid just for that.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your answer.

Comment: @BenoitHenry Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way but i'm not really with my code. 
I had to add counter modifier on each element of the grid to put it on the right space.

HTML :

```
<main class="render render--2 container">
    <div class="render__view--bg"></div>

    <div class="render__params render__params--1">
        <span class="font-name">Maven Pro</span>
    </div>

    <div class="render__view render__view--1">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>    </div>


    <div class="render__params render__params--2">
        <span class="font-name">Quintessential</span>
    </div>

    <div class="render__view render__view--2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce egestas vestibulum mauris, id accumsan dolor. Fusce interdum sit amet purus et imperdiet. Nulla porta tortor ante, a cursus nisi varius vitae. Maecenas eu faucibus velit. Sed varius nulla ac facilisis tempus. Vestibulum aliquet varius consequat. Nullam augue dui, auctor non vehicula quis, eleifend et ex. Curabitur sit amet purus rutrum, rhoncus est non, ornare ex. Aenean lobortis nibh ut ante vestibulum ornare. Maecenas posuere odio nec mollis consectetur. Quisque non leo nec quam congue commodo eu non est.</p>

<p>In sit amet nisi urna. Integer vehicula massa quis risus tristique, eu condimentum metus fringilla. Nunc ex ipsum, suscipit eget ullamcorper ut, faucibus non risus. Fusce consectetur risus nec tellus malesuada posuere. Curabitur quam libero, efficitur at malesuada a, venenatis in lectus. Ut aliquam auctor ullamcorper. In pretium, elit vel mollis ultrices, sem leo dignissim turpis, in blandit nunc dui et leo.</p>

<p>Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet velit id nunc placerat aliquet et in quam. Praesent eu laoreet felis. Nulla non nibh libero. Nulla in tellus ac mauris lacinia vulputate ac vitae mi. Pellentesque eleifend non massa id pellentesque. Nam fermentum, ante eget consectetur sodales, dui augue faucibus justo, eu posuere est sapien eu sapien.</p>    </div>

</main>
```

And CSS :

```
//CSS Grid
.render{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;

    &.render--2{
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
        grid-template-areas: 
    "params view"
    "params view";
    }

    &.render--3{
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
        grid-template-areas: 
    "params view"
    "params view"
    "params view";
    }

    .render__view--bg{
        z-index: 1;
        grid-column: view-start / view-end;
    grid-row: view 1 / view 3;
        background: #fff none;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }

    .render__params,
    .render__view{
        padding: 16px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .render__params{
        grid-column: params / span 1;

    &--1{
          grid-row: params 1;
    }

    &--2{
          grid-row: params 2;
    }

    &--3{
          grid-row: params 3;
    }
    }

    .render__view{
        grid-column: view / span 1;

        &--1{
          grid-row: view 1;
    }

    &--2{
          grid-row: view 2;
    }

    &--3{
          grid-row: view 3;
    }
    }
}
```

Here's the [Codepen preview](https://codepen.io/bhenbe/pen/eEBwbP)

Thank you all for your help !